# Chart from Power BI from a user in an IFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe, charts, web, powerbi

I am creating a webpage that will display charts from a Power BI dashboard.
Upon entering the website the user must log in with their Office 365 account, so that I can access their dashboard and display their charts on my webpage.

Any leads on how I can put a specific chart in an `iframe`?

Example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2014/02/28/the-oscars-with-power-bi.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Update: Since I originally answered this question, much has changed.

In application embedding: if you're building a secure web site and want to embed content from a user's Power BI account, you can use our [tile and report embedding capabilities](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/). At the link you'll find documentation and samples to get you started.

Public anonymous embedding: if you're a blogger, journalist, or organization looking to embed reports publicly to share data or tell a story using data, you can use the [Power BI Publish to web feature](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-power-bi-publish-to-web/).  It allows you to take a report from your Power BI account and with a few clicks publish it so anyone on the internet can view and access it.

As always if you're looking for a new feature head over to our [ideas site](https://ideas.powerbi.com) so we can let you know when we've completed items you've asked for.

Comment: Yes! I revised my answer see above.